# qwt отображение по оси абсцисс даты времени

Tags: c++, qt

В .log пишу состояние сенсора. Запись произвожу раз в час, то есть дискрет между точками равен 60 минутам. Запись циклическая с периодом 1 год. Вот и возникает вопрос как можно в qwt по оси абсцисс отобразить время вместо точек дискретизации? Для удобства чтения данных.

Что сделал. Читаю данные времени из файла:

```
    QFile file("/media/usbhd-sda1/StateBatteries.log");
    if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly |
              QFile::Text))
     {
     qDebug() << "Could not open file for reading";
     }
     else
     {
     QTextStream in(&file);

     QStringList lineData;

    lineData = QString(in.readLine()).split(" ");

    QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString(lineData[0] + " " + lineData[1], 
    "dd.MMM.yy hh:mm:ss");

    qDebug() << dt.toString("dd.MMM.yy hh:mm:ss");
```

qDebug выдает  `"03.мар.20 10:06:15"`

файл который считываю имеет вот такой формат:
    03.мар.20 10:06:15 13066 13056 12752 13042 13118 12621 12979 12584 13074 
    12864 13375 12853 14313 12571 12609 12869 12800 12539 и так далее.

Как можно отобразить на оси времени параметр `dt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с Qwt 6.1 можно использовать [QwtDateScaleDraw](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_date_scale_draw.html) и, по необходимости, [QwtDateScaleEngine](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_date_scale_engine.html).

---

Пример на основе `simpleplot`:

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include <qwt_plot_grid.h>
#include <qwt_symbol.h>
#include <qwt_legend.h>

#include <QDateTime>
#include <qwt_date.h>
#include <qwt_date_scale_engine.h>
#include <qwt_date_scale_draw.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    QwtPlot plot;
    plot.setTitle( "Plot Demo" );
    plot.setCanvasBackground( Qt::white );
    plot.setAxisScale( QwtPlot::yLeft, 0.0, 10.0 );
    plot.insertLegend( new QwtLegend() );
    plot.setAxisScaleDraw( QwtPlot::xBottom, new QwtDateScaleDraw);
    plot.setAxisScaleEngine( QwtPlot::xBottom, new QwtDateScaleEngine);

    QwtPlotGrid *grid = new QwtPlotGrid();
    grid->attach( &plot );

    QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
    curve->setTitle( "Some Points" );
    curve->setPen( Qt::blue, 4 );
    curve->setRenderHint( QwtPlotItem::RenderAntialiased, true );

    QwtSymbol *symbol = new QwtSymbol( QwtSymbol::Ellipse,
        QBrush( Qt::yellow ), QPen( Qt::red, 2 ), QSize( 8, 8 ) );
    curve->setSymbol( symbol );

    QPolygonF points;
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
      points << QPointF( QwtDate::toDouble(QDateTime(QDate::currentDate().addDays(i))),
                         rand()*10.0/RAND_MAX );
    }
    curve->setSamples( points );

    curve->attach( &plot );

    plot.resize( 800, 600 );
    plot.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

[image: Скриншот с графиком]

---

Также смотри пример `stockchart`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105185/discussion-on-answer-by-fat-zer-qwt------).